# How to extract rater values?

Tags: r, raster

I have 10 raster images and I want to extract the values of each raster image independently in a same csv file i.e., column 1 have raster 1 value, column 2 has raster 2 value and so on. Can any expert help me here. I am very tense now. I am doing this on R.

Your cooperation needs

Comment: If you're tense, loosen up and read [ask] and don't forget to edit your question with a [mre].

Comment: What programming language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: SIR I am using R .

Comment: You should add a sample input image and wanted output ... what exactly you want to achieve ... what values? are those images of text/numbers and you want to OCR or you want to detect some stuff from image like temperature from IR image ... without all this we do not know what you have and want and can not help as none of us know what you are doing other than what you write/share ... I added the `[r]` tag tags are very important for post searching so if you chose wrong ones then the right people will not see your post ...

Answer (score 1):

For the example I use the same file four times

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
ff <- c(f, f, f, f)
```

Now with your filenames `ff` you can do

```
r <- rast(ff)
v <- values(r)
```

You may first want to remove `NA`s

```
v <- na.omit(v)
head(v, 3)
#     elevation elevation elevation elevation
#[1,]       529       529       529       529
#[2,]       542       542       542       542
#[3,]       547       547       547       547
```

And write to file

```
write.csv(v, "test.csv")
```

If you do not want all values, but only those overlapping with polygons, lines, or points, you could use `extract`. Here for two points:

```
p <- cbind(c(6,6.2), c(50,49.7))
e <- extract(r, p)
e
#  elevation elevation.1 elevation.2 elevation.3
#1       406         406         406         406
#2       320         320         320         320

write.csv(e, "test.csv")
```

You could accomplish the same with the old `raster` package

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(ff)
v <- values(s)
write.csv(v, "test.csv")

p <- cbind(c(6,6.2), c(50,49.7))
e <- extract(s, p)
write.csv(e, "test.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily implemented by stacking your rasters into a single stack, then using `raster::extract` to extract the values you then need to convert this into a dataframe, and name your raster columns appropriately.

To use `extract` you will need a spatial dataset of which you can extract specific values from the raster.

Here's an example using some dummy data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
set.seed(2013)
#create a dataframe with some x, y and z coordiantes
df <- data.frame( x = rep( 0:1, each=2 ),
                  y = rep( 0:1,  2),
                  l = rnorm( 4 ))
spg <- df
#conver to coordinates
coordinates(spg) <- ~ x + y
# coerce to SpatialPixelsDataFrame
gridded(spg) <- TRUE
# coerce to raster
#create raster
rasterDF <- raster(spg)
#assign ten of these
one_1 <-  rasterDF
#write them
writeRaster(one_1, "one_1.tif", overwrite = TRUE)

#Let's say I have repeated the above 10 times and I now have 10 rasters saved.
#call them into the environment by stacking the tif files and assign them onto a variable
trythis <- list.files("try/", "^one_", 
                        full.names = TRUE) %>% stack()

I get this:
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 2, 2, 4, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -0.5, 1.5, -0.5, 1.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
names      :      one_1,     one_10,      one_2,      one_3,      one_4,      one_5,      one_6,      one_7,      one_8,      one_9 
min values : -0.6674423, -1.4290716, -0.6674423, -0.6674423, -0.6674423, -0.6674423, -0.6674423,  0.1694666, -0.6985107, -1.2569902 
max values :  1.3606115,  0.4721121,  1.3606115,  1.3606115,  1.3606115,  1.3606115,  1.3606115,  1.3580687,  0.9472504, -0.2056757 

Now you can extract the values under a for loop, or any looping mechanism:
#assign an ampty variable
test.this.out <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(names(trythis))){
#loop all layers
  test.this.out[[i]] <- raster::extract(trythis[[i]], spg)
}
#convert lists into data frame by column
test.this.out <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, test.this.out) 
#change column names
colnames(test.this.out) <- c("raster1","raster2","raster3","raster4","raster5","raster6","raster7","raster8","raster9","raster10")

#Finally
      raster1    raster2     raster3     raster4     raster5     raster6     raster7   raster8    raster9   raster10
1 -0.09202453 -1.1024133 -0.09202453 -0.09202453 -0.09202453 -0.09202453 -0.09202453 0.5890492 -0.6985106 -0.5292692
2  0.78901911  0.4721121  0.78901911  0.78901911  0.78901911  0.78901911  0.78901911 1.1447455  0.4295670 -0.5063994
3 -0.66744232 -1.4290715 -0.66744232 -0.66744232 -0.66744232 -0.66744232 -0.66744232 0.1694666 -0.5523508 -0.2056757
4  1.36061144 -0.1336733  1.36061144  1.36061144  1.36061144  1.36061144  1.36061144 1.3580687  0.9472504 -1.2569902
```